# C# in MVVM, how to get result of default ValueConvertor

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

When I input text "abc" into TextBox Control,

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding V1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

where V1 is UInt16 property in ViewModel

```
    private UInt16 _V1;
    public UInt16 V1
    {
        get { return _V1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _V1, value); }
    }
```

UI will notify validation error, but in ViewModel's EventHandler I can't find out that error is happened, and what text is actually inputed.
So what's the right way to go on, thanks

Comment: Please indicate the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

To send data from the UI to your VM, you first need to set the binding mode to `TwoWay`.

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextInput, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Then, you need to adjust your ViewModel to expose a `string` property because `TextBox.Text` is a `string` property and therefore cannot be two-way bound to a numeric type directly.

Instead you can use 2 properties in your VM.

- One for the raw string.
- One for the numeric value.

Based on your need, you can set one property from the setter of the other.

```cs
private string _textInput;
public string TextInput
{
    get { return _textInput; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_textInput != value)
        {
            SetProperty(ref _textInput, value);
        
            // Validate that value is valid, then set the V1 property. 
            if (UInt16.TryParse(value, out var number))
            {
                V1 = number;
            }
        }
    }
}

private UInt16 _V1;
public UInt16 V1
{
    get { return _V1; }
    set
    { 
        if (_V1 != value)
        {
            SetProperty(ref _V1, value);
            
            // You can set TextInput automatically when setting V1.
            TextInput = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added some `if` checks to prevent a stack overflow of infinite updates.